# Dlookup value shows 0

Tags: ms-access

while using Dlookup to find a "part No" while using a textbox and entering Part no that will match to the last date entry and bring all information .

```
Dim prtn As String
Dim temppart As String
Dim lastdate As Date
temppart = Me.Part_No.Value

lastdate = Nz(DMax("[Date Of Purchase]", "StockInventory", "[Part No]= '" & temppart & "'"), 0)

prtn = Nz(DLookup("[Part No]", "[StockList Query]", "[Part No]='" & temppart & "' AND [Date Of Purchase]= " & Format(lastdate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")), 0)
```

here i can see lastdate carry last date, temppart carry the part no but value in prtn shows 0 ..

Comment: `[StockList Query]`may not contain`Max([Date Of Purchase]`of`StockInventory`or`[StockList Query].[Date Of Purchase]`is a datetime, but`StockInventory.[Date Of Purchase]`is only a date (or opposite)? Show query sql, sample data, expected result, actual result.

Comment: ahh thank you lot ... yes in the query i dint use date of purchase ... my issue has got resolve... Thank you so mch

Comment: Please add your solution as answer, so others may benefit!

Answer (score 0):

ComputerVersteher: missing of data column which was cause to get value '0' issue resolved after adding the column to the current query.